# Canonical Tag Not Being Recognized

Tags: seo, google, html, search-engines, canonical-url

I'm puzzled by the first [Google search result](https://www.google.ie/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=http://seatgeek.com/colorado-buffaloes-basketball-tickets&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=1&cad=b&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.) in this list.

The first result has the following rel="canonical" tag:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://seatgeek.com/colorado-buffaloes-basketball-tickets/" />
```

So shouldn't the URL in the tag be indexed instead of the one with "?date=2011-03-29" on the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would think so, however [Google has explicitly stated](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) that the `rel=canonical` link element is a **hint** for search engines - as opposed to a **directive** (such as a redirect).

We have implemented rel-con on a site with 2+ million pages indexed and see a large proportion of non-canonical URLs indexed. I believe this may correct over time, but at this stage Google (et.al) are taking their time to analyse the implementation.